# Problem during production of LaTeX book with plasTeX (with many packages on it) into HTML5 website

Tags: packages, conversion, html

I want to ask if there is a way to generate my book that I currently have in LaTeX format into an HTML5/XHTML website so that I can upload it to Internet. My book will be designed into a format with many chapters and subchapters so that the user will be able to move into directories from one another.

I have already tried plasTeX, which is great, but I have a problem with recognizing my  packages and it produces errors during the conversion.

How can I solve this error? Or can I use another tool, with a full package support, if there is one?

My packages are the following:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SX! You would first need to provide a minimal working example (the smallest example of a complete document that produces the error) and show us exactly which errors you are being given. (Also, you should make an account on this site, too! Your question was migrated.)  Have you looked at `tex4ht`?

Comment: Hello Sean! I am happy that I am in here after some experience that I did have with stackoverflow and askubuntu forums. I wanted to try PlasTeX and I had tex4ht as my backup solution. But I came to a solution and I just posted the results as a new answer for possible future inquiries of other people. Thanks for your concern. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlasTeX can handle all of those packages except {acronym} and {chapterbib}. My solution was this:

- removing those 2 packages
- removing babel import for Greek language that I did have inside. As
  it seems, PlasTeX can automatically recognize Greek language and the
  babel import generates a lot of errors.